# iPhone - sending an action from one UIViewController to another?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a login view controller that appears only if a user is not logged-in.

After being logged-in, the view is removed.

My question: how would I send an action to the view controller that requested the login view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18) or a [target-action](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW14) approach. In the end you will give the login view some information about your view controller so that it will be notified once login is complete.

Ex.

```
//Your view controller
loginView.delegate = self;

...

//loginView code
-(void)loginComplete
{
    [self.delegate loginComplete:self];
}
```

Comment: I ended up using UINotificationcenter - worked really well, no need to use delgates and keeps code very clean i think.